# How to center a Bootstrap dropdown textbox or menu below its button?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing a simple dropdown textbox for a button on a navbar.  For some reason, the text will not drop below the button.  It was showing up to the left, blocking the brand.  Then I made the dropdown-menu position:relative, and now it shows up to the right, and expands the navbar downward.  I tried changing the margins on it as well, and nothing. 
 I just want it to show up below the button, below the navbar.  Not sure why this isn't working?

Pretty much copied it directly from Bootstrap site, and am importing my jquery, JS, and css appropriately.  What am I doing wrong?

#### HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">news</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown show">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        How It Works
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <div class="dropdown-item"> Click </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

#### CSS

```
/*NAV*/
.navbar-header .navbar-brand{
  color: rgb(97, 100, 206);
  font-size: 2.0em;
}


.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 88);
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  /*align-self: center;*/
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown button {
  /*background-color: #4446ce;*/
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(163, 163, 179);
  border: .5px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
```

#### scripts

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <title>AetherNews</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:900" rel="stylesheet">




</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, remove `show` from `<div class="dropdown show">`; in your CSS remove `position: relative` from `.dropdown-menu`:

```css
/*NAV*/

.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: rgb(97, 100, 206);
  font-size: 2.0em;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 88);
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  /*align-self: center;*/
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
}

.dropdown button {
  /*background-color: #4446ce;*/
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(163, 163, 179);
  border: .5px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">news</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        How It Works
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <div class="dropdown-item"> Click </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Strange though - it works great in your code snippet, but not in my code.  I'm using Chrome, and tried in Firefox, as well.

Comment: Strange... Do you have your full code available somewhere? Maybe put it in a [codepen?](https://codepen.io/)

Comment: Here's a codepen of what's happening:  

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPOwaR

Thanks for taking a look, I appreciate it.

update:  Just realized that, while it still isn't working in codepen, it is behaving a bit differently.  In the codepen, the box pops up to the left and covers the nav.  In my browser, it pops up to the right, and expands the nav height.  But perhaps a fix would take care of both behaviors...

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` to `.dropdown`.
https://codepen.io/pixleight/pen/wdEqby

Comment: It didn't work!  But works in codepen.  hahaha wtf.  Maybe I have to start from scratch